# Is it possible to change the Hybrid maptype as an StyledMapType?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

I was wondering if you could change the features of the hybrid maptype like you can do on a styledmaptype. I ask this because i want to show the satellite map (or changed hybrid map) with only country borders, no roads citynames etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may observe the event **maptypeid_changed** of the map.

Check the current mapTypeId  by using getMapTypeId() and if it is equal to `google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID` apply the following style to the map by using `map.setOptions()`

```
{
    featureType: "all",
    elementType: "labels",//hides all labels
    stylers: [
      { visibility:'off' }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "road",//hides the roads
    stylers: [
      { visibility:'off' }
    ]
  }
```

When the mapTypeId is not `google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID` apply the same style, but set both visibility-stylers to **on**

In the end it may look like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'maptypeid_changed', function() {

  var onoff=(this.getMapTypeId()==google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID)
              ?'off'
              :'on';

             this.setOptions(
                {
                  styles:[{
                            featureType: "all",
                            elementType: "labels",
                            stylers: [{ visibility:onoff }]
                          },
                          {
                            featureType: "road",
                            stylers: [{ visibility:onoff}]}
                        ]
                }
                );

});
google.maps.event.trigger(map,'maptypeid_changed');
```